How to install curlftpfs on ubuntu 24.04 LTS : Package 'curlftpfs' has no installation candidate
I'm trying to install curlftpfs on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS but it fails although the universe repository is enabled :
$ sudo apt install curlftpfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package curlftpfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curlftpfs' has no installation candidate
$

And I see no Launchpad PPA containing curlftpfs for Ubuntu 24.04.
How do I install or build curlftpfs on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ?

Judging from their homepage, this project looks dead. Maybe that's why it's no longer included in the Universe repo.

@ArturMeinild Is there a curlftpfs successor or fork ?

@ArturMeinild How can I build curlftpfs from Ubuntu 23.10 curlftpfs source package ?

I don't know...

@ArturMeinild OK, I will ask this as another question to the community then.

@ArturMeinild I found curlftpfs-ng.

I posted my other question here.

Edit the sources.list file
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Add the following line to the end
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe

Save and close the file then
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curlftpfs

Then edit the sources.list file and remove the repo again.

Not necessarily a good idea - in any case, you might want to remove the Focal repo again.
